# Using em for navigation sidebar - what unit to use for remaining body container?

Tags: css

I have a webpage with a sidebar that has navigation options for the site.  The sidebar is a width of 6em (right: 0px, height: 100%, position: fixed).

I want the rest of the content to utilize most of the remainder of the page (100% of total width, minus 7em).

Right now, I'm using percent on the main content - is there a smarter/better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, keep the 100% width on the remaining page and add

> padding-left: 7em;

(your remaining page should be placed inside a containing div)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing some HTML, but I'd simply set your content div to 100% width and add right padding of 7em to accommodate the sidebar. What you do inside the content div is at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

If the main content is `display: block`, it will use up the entire usable area by default.  There is no need to specify it to `100%` width.  To make sure there is no overlap, give it a right margin of `6em` (or whatever the width of the navigation bar is).  Depending upon some of your inner element styles, there may be problems, but it's unlikely.

http://jsfiddle.net/XFaeZ/

Notice how "content" is visible even though it's floated to the right.  If the `#content` div were set at `width: 100%`, its margin would extend *past* the width of the page and "content" would be obscured.